# curl https://google.com/ not working

Tags: curl, https

I am trying to fetch the details of google.com using curl. But I am getting the below error. I checked a lot of posts /blogs on internet but could not make it work.

I want it to be secure, so I cant use "-k" option.

Os Details

```
root@ubuntu-amd64:/etc/ssl/certs# uname -a
Linux ubuntu-amd64 3.13.0-135-generic #184-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 18 11:55:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Error

```
root@ubuntu-amd64:/etc/ssl/certs#
root@ubuntu-amd64:/etc/ssl/certs# curl  https://google.com/
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
root@ubuntu-amd64:/etc/ssl/certs#
```

Comment: Did you do `apt-get install ca-certificates` and `update-ca-certificates`?

Comment: Yes I had done it earlier.

Comment: root@ubuntu-amd64:/etc/ssl/certs# apt-get install ca-certificates
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ca-certificates is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 227 not upgraded.
root@ubuntu-amd64:/etc/ssl/certs# update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs... 0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d....done.
root@ubuntu-amd64:/etc/ssl/certs#

Comment: This might be better suited on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com)